# How to create headers for dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating the dynamic table based on user input. I know how to create headers but I want to display headers something like this.

1. Table Header: |Label|Control|Label|Control|Label|Control|
2. And also, how to make cells editable.

Can someone suggests me how can I do this?

Thanks.

[table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXvYa.png)

```js
function CreateTable() {
    var rowCtr;
    var cellCtr;
    var rowCnt;
    var cellCnt;
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
    var table = document.createElement('Table');
    table.border = '1';
    table.id = 'myTable';
    var tableBody = document.createElement('Tbody');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    rowCnt = document.getElementById('txtrows').value;
    cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;
    for (var rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rowCnt; rowCtr++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        for (var cellCtr = 0; cellCtr < cellCnt; cellCtr++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.width = '120';
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click me, Row:" + rowCtr + " Column:" + cellCtr));
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Row Count</td>
        <td>Column Count</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtrows" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtcols"/></td>
        <td><button onclick="CreateTable()">Create Table</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>



<div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
```

Comment: [`contenteditable`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)?

Comment: to be able to edit the rows you need to append <input>  fields as well inside the <tr>

Comment: It is not clear what you want in the header. What do you mean by "Label|Control" repeated several times?

Comment: By the way, take a look to the [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element, it may simplify your code for the creation of the normal cells.

Comment: `  document.getElementById("myTable").contentEditable = true;` i tried this, not working. can you please suggest me how can i apply this

Comment: yes it should repeat. I have attach a image of sample table please have a look. @Acorn

Comment: ` document.getElementById("myTable").contentEditable = true;` i tried this, not working. can you please suggest me how can i apply this @WaisKamal

Comment: Place quotes around true ("true").

Comment: yeah , its working now. @WaisKamal Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> table.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");

will make it editable , check this out

```js
function CreateTable() {
    var rowCtr;
    var cellCtr;
    var rowCnt;
    var cellCnt;
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
    var table = document.createElement('Table');
    table.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    table.border = '1';
    table.id = 'myTable';
    var tableBody = document.createElement('Tbody');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    rowCnt = document.getElementById('txtrows').value;
    cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;
    for (var rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rowCnt; rowCtr++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        for (var cellCtr = 0; cellCtr < cellCnt; cellCtr++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.width = '120';
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click me, Row:" + rowCtr + " Column:" + cellCtr));
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
    }
```

```html
<table contenteditable = "true">
    <tr>
        <td>Row Count</td>
        <td>Column Count</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtrows" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtcols"/></td>
        <td><button onclick="CreateTable()">Create Table</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>



<div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
```

> check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618485/create-table-column-headers-dynamically) on How to create headers for dynamic table

Comment: Thanks @T.Shashwat. The post you have shared for creating table headers is also works but, how can i repeat headers like if i give input as 5*5 then the table header should be ( Label | Control | Label | Control | Label.) display like this. Any idea??

Comment: table header is inside for loop of number of columns so headers will be be equal to number of columns created ,  .appendChild(th) is used for same

Answer (score 0):

Creating repeated headers for dynamic table.

```js
    function CreateTable() {
        var rowCtr;
        var cellCtr;
        var rowCnt;
        var cellCnt;
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
        var table = document.createElement('Table');
        table.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
        table.border = '1';
        table.id = 'myTable';

    var Header = ["Label", "Control"];
        var thead = document.createElement('thead');
        table.appendChild(thead);
      cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;
        for (var i = 0; i < cellCnt; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                thead.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).
                    appendChild(document.createTextNode(Header[0]));
            }
            else {
                thead.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).
                    appendChild(document.createTextNode(Header[1]));
            }
        }

        var tableBody = document.createElement('Tbody');
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        rowCnt = document.getElementById('txtrows').value;
        cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;
        for (var rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rowCnt; rowCtr++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tableBody.appendChild(tr);
            for (var cellCtr = 0; cellCtr < cellCnt; cellCtr++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.width = '120';
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click me, Row:" + rowCtr + " Column:" + cellCtr));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
        myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
        }
```

```html
    <table contenteditable = "true">
        <tr>
            <td>Row Count</td>
            <td>Column Count</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtrows" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtcols"/></td>
            <td><button onclick="CreateTable()">Create Table</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    <div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
```